# Kurdish text not displaying properly in contact from

Tags: php, html, contacts

I made a simple contact form using HTML & PHP and I tested, it works perfectly, but when I wanna write in Kurdish or Arabic language the text not displaying properly in my email it looks like that: **ÚÛØ¨ÛÙ**

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_mobile = $_POST['cf_mobile'];
$field_service = $_POST['cf_service'];
$field_customer = $_POST['cf_customer'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

$mail_to = 'email@email.co';
$subject = 'داواکاری بینینی بەڕێوەبەران';

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'mobile: '.$field_mobile."\n";
$body_message .= 'Manager: '.$field_service."\n";
$body_message .= 'Sender: '.$field_customer."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message send successfully :)');
        window.location = 'https://#.co/interview';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Failed :( Please call the developer!');
        window.location = 'https://#/interview';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: You can try [`mb_convert_encoding()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php). `$body_message = mb_convert_encoding($body_message, 'UTF-8')`

Comment: I tried, it looks the same ÙØ¥ÙØ§Øº

Comment: You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19830274/1331040) answer out as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
mail( $mail_to, utf8_decode($subject), utf8_decode($body_message), utf8_decode($headers) );
```